# Order One Crossover in Java Genetic Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic

So basically i am creating a genetic algorithm but i am stuck when it comes to implementing the crossover code. Can anyone lend a helping hand to let me know if my code is a step in the right direction when implementing order one crossover. Or can anyone give me pseudo code for order one crossover?

```
package geneticalgorithm;

import java.util.Random;

public class GeneticAlgorithm {

final static int P = 20;
final static int N = 10;
static int popFitness = 0;  
int offspringFitness = 0;
static Random rand = new Random();
static int count = 0;

   static Individual[]  population = new Individual[P];
   static Individual[] offspring = new Individual[P];


public static void main(String[] args) {



    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++){


        population[i] = new Individual(); //Generates a population of P individuals and gives each one unique genes
        population[i].generateGenes();
        population[i].fitness = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){                //    Loops through each individual in the population and assesses their
            if (population[i].genes[j] == 1 ){       //fitness based on how many 1's are in its genes
                population[i].fitness++;

            }
        }    
    }  

    for (int i = 0; i < P ; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
         count++;

        System.out.print(population[i].genes[j]  ); // Loops through population and each gene and outputs each individuals genes to the screen aswell as there fitness
     if ((count % N) == 0){
         System.out.print( "    " + population[i].fitness);
         System.out.println("");
     }
    }
    }




    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++){

        popFitness += population[i].fitness; // calculates the overall fitness of the population
    }

    System.out.println(popFitness);


   offspring[1] = population[rouletteSelection()];
    System.out.println(offspring[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++){

        int p1 = rand.nextInt(P);
        int p2 = rand.nextInt(P);

        if (population[p1].fitness >= population[p2].fitness){
                offspring[i] = population[p1];
        }
            else {                                       //Randomly creates a new population called offspring by comparing two random parents 
                offspring[i] = population[p2];          //and picking the one with the largest fitness value
                        }

        }


} 




 public static Individual crossover1(Individual parent1, Individual parent2){
    Individual newSol = new Individual();
    parent1 = population[rouletteSelection()];
    parent2 = population[rouletteSelection()];
    int crossoverPoint = rand.nextInt(N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        Individual newSolution = new Individual();

    for (int i = 0; i == crossoverPoint; i++){

        newSolution.setGenes(i, parent1.getGenes(i));
        }
    for (int i = crossoverPoint; i < N; i++){
        newSolution.setGenes(i, parent2.getGenes(i));
    }
    }
return null;} 



public static int rouletteSelection(){
int parent = 0;
int randNum = rand.nextInt(popFitness);
int rollingSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < P; i++){
    rollingSum += population[i].fitness;  //Algorithm to select a         parent based on probability and a hint of randomness
    if (rollingSum >= randNum){
         parent = i;
        break;
    }
 } System.out.println(parent);
 return parent;

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your crossover function looks good to me, but you just never seem to return the new individual:

```
public static Individual crossover1(Individual parent1, Individual parent2){
     Individual newSol = new Individual();
     parent1 = population[rouletteSelection()];
     parent2 = population[rouletteSelection()];
     int crossoverPoint = rand.nextInt(N);
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){

     for (int i = 0; i == crossoverPoint; i++){

         newSol.setGenes(i, parent1.getGenes(i));
      }
    for (int i = crossoverPoint; i < N; i++){
       newSol.setGenes(i, parent2.getGenes(i));
     }
    }
    return newSol;
}
```